# How to edit question tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

Item 1 in the Plan in [The Great Re-Tagging Call to Arms](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386/the-great-re-tagging-call-to-arms?cb=1) is

> When you view a new question (especially if the question has only 1 tag), compare its tags to the question's content. If another tag applies, add it.

Regarding this item, I was going to point out how to edit question tags least obtrusively, “by hovering next to the tags list and clicking *edit tags*” but then found out that that option isn't appearing for me for ELL questions ([1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/function-of-these-two-thats/3815#3815), [2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/901/is-there-a-grammatical-rule-impeding-the-presence-of-for-in-i-have-lived-here), [3](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28/which-pronunciation-of-either-is-correct)).  (It does appear when hovering next to or over the tags list of [an ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41333/origin-of-you-lot-and-other-plural-forms-of-you) or [another ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35972/origin-and-status-of-hosed-meaning-broken).)

I presume it isn't a reputation issue, since [the ELL faq](https://ell.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) shows 200 points is adequate for the “Retag questions” privilege.  Can this feature be added in ELL as well as in ELU?  Or is it already here but for some reason not available to me?

Comment: This is odd...  The "edit tags" option does appear for me on ELL, and I've checked the three questions you linked specifically as well--all fine here. Maybe try logging out and logging back in, and see if that helps? If not, I'll investigate this and get back with you. (EDIT: Figured it out--see answer below.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Help Center that replaced the FAQ now correctly explains what reputation (2k) is required to gain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is the following:

- When you get the "retag questions" privilege, for each questions you will see a "retag" link that allows you to edit only the tags
- When you get the "edit questions and answers" privilege, that link will vanish, and to edit the tags you need to edit the question
- Once you get the "access to moderator tools" privilege, you will see an "Edit tags" link when you hover the mouse on the zone to the right of the tags showed for a question

Notice that when you have the "retag questions" privilege it can happen you don't see the "retag" link; it happens when there is a pending suggested edit that needs to be approved/rejected. The same applies for the "edit" link when there are pending suggested edit for the question.

#### Reference

- The [page for the "retag questions" privilege](https://ell.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions)
- The [page for the "access to moderation tools" privilege](https://ell.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: The "retag questions" privilege [has been removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186945/215040).  This answer may need to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature that is only available to those with access to the Moderator Tools panel.  This requires 2k reputation on a beta site, and 10k once we graduate.  You can find more information at the bottom of the Moderator Tools Privileges information page [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools).